# Convert and insert two date formats MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm facing an issue with managinging dates, some dates pass others dont. I want to produce an insertable date for mysql. there are two possible types of post dates

```
yyyy-mm-dd //should go without conversion
m/d/yyyy  // should be converted
```

I'm using this

```
 $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
 $date_regex = '/(0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](19|20)\d\d/';
 if(preg_match($date_regex, $date)){
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$date)->format('Y-m-d');}
```

**problems**

I realised this regex is failing for dates like

```
2/5/2013
```

but has been working for

```
 12/12/2013
```

so I removed it BUT still

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

is also failing for m/d/yyyy

This date thing has got my head spinning for the last 6 hours.

Comment: Do you mean `m/d/yyy` or `m/d/yyyy` ?

Comment: I have corrected it yyyy

Comment: Use explode on "/" and create a valid date format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there is no need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` because `m/d/yyyy` is one of the [recognized date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) (see "American month, day and year"). Just convert it to a `DateTime` object and let the constructor handle the format and forget the regex:

```
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
$datex = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
```

The reason `DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$date)` fails for dates like `2/5/2013` is because you are forcing it to be specifically 'm/d/Y' and that date does *not* fit that pattern. You can see a list of all date formats [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Specifically, `m` expects there to be a leading zero (like `02`), so when you give it one without that, it won't recognize it. Same goes for `d`. In this case you would have to use `n` and `j` respectively. But, like I said, let the constructor do the hard work for you.